# Android: Make view equal to parent width -20 dip?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to set a layouts width to be the width of it's parent -20 dip? I'm dealing with a `Tablerow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving TableRow

```
android:paddingRight="10dip" android:paddingLeft="10dip"
```

which makes it look like its width is 20dpi less than that of parent.

Answer (score 2):

Set its left and right padding as needed.

```
<TableRow
   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   android:paddingRight="10dp"
   ...
/>
```

Comment: Padding is not a `layout_` attribute, margin is. So, this should be `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` or `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight`.